# How to make my android app method less RAM consuming

Tags: java, android, xml, ram

I was looking for some advice on making my application more RAM friendly. On a larger android tablet device the app works fine and I'm testing on a HTC Desire S running Android 2.3.5 which I know is an ANCIENT phone by today's standards but whenever I try to run this method the phone will FORCE CLOSE. I was wondering if there was any advice people could provide with modifying my code to make it a bit more efficient in terms of RAM.

Please see below my android method and my logcat printout:

**Android activity method**

```
public void uploadDataToCrowdSnapCymru() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nameString));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", descString));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", latString));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lngString));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", projectString));

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("snap", ba1));

    try {
        //EXECUTE POST
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://users.aber.ac.uk/dwd/mfb/php/receiveUserData.php");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(responseText);

        if(responseText != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Record uploaded! View it at CrowdSnapCymru.com", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());

    }
}
```

**LogCat printout**

```
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/dalvikvm(8950): Out of memory: Heap Size=9927KB, Allocated=5369KB, Bitmap Size=8756KB, Limit=20480KB
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/dalvikvm(8950): Extra info: Footprint=9927KB, Allowed Footprint=9927KB, Trimmed=504KB
05-15 23:52:55.938: D/AndroidRuntime(8950): Shutting down VM
05-15 23:52:55.938: W/dalvikvm(8950): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=9927KB, Allocated=5369KB, Bitmap Size=8756KB)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122) 
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.UploadRecord.uploadDataToCrowdSnapCymru(UploadRecord.java:119)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at rcahmw.prototype.crowdsnapcymru.UploadRecord$1.onClick(UploadRecord.java:85)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-15 23:52:55.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

Any advice anyone could provide would be well received. ALSO a final question will `HTTP POST` methods work on a mobile network as well as Wi-Fi? Thanks. I'm assuming they do as internet browsers apps work on both network and wifi and its kind of the same principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're compressing photo into a JPEG at quality 100. A lower quality may or may not have a visible impact, but almost certainly will be smaller. Try 50.
2. You're putting the compressed image into a byte array, which you then immediately base64 encode into a string. Since the byte array is an intermediary, release it as soon as you don't need it any more, by setting ba = null. If you can recycle and release the original photo bitmap, do so as well: "photo.recycle(); photo = null;"
3. You upload a base64 string. Consider using multipart form data, which can stream the bitmap directly from the compressed ByteArrayOutputStream. In this way you wouldn't need two intermediate representations at all. See:
   [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

POST will work fine on a mobile network, but will be slower. If you're uploading a large image, then it'll take awhile. This is another reason to compress the JPEG image with a lower quality.